# How to rewrite a simple tokenizer to use regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, url-rewriting, tokenize, lexer

This an optimized version of the tokenizer that was first written, and it works fairly well. A secondary tokenizer can parse the output from this function to create classified tokens of greater specificity.

```
def tokenize(source):
    return (token for token in (token.strip() for line
            in source.replace('\r\n', '\n').replace('\r', '\n').split('\n')
            for token in line.split('#', 1)[0].split(';')) if token)
```

My question is this: *how can this be written simply with the `re` module?* Below is my ineffective attempt.

```
def tokenize2(string):
    search = re.compile(r'^(.+?)(?:;(.+?))*?(?:#.+)?$', re.MULTILINE)
    for match in search.finditer(string):
        for item in match.groups():
            yield item
```

**Edit:** This is the type of output that I am looking for from the tokenizer. Parsing the text should be easy.

```
>>> def tokenize(source):
    return (token for token in (token.strip() for line
            in source.replace('\r\n', '\n').replace('\r', '\n').split('\n')
            for token in line.split('#', 1)[0].split(';')) if token)

>>> for token in tokenize('''\
a = 1 + 2; b = a - 3 # create zero in b
c = b * 4; d = 5 / c # trigger div error

e = (6 + 7) * 8
# try a boolean operation
f = 0 and 1 or 2
a; b; c; e; f'''):
    print(repr(token))


'a = 1 + 2'
'b = a - 3 '
'c = b * 4'
'd = 5 / c '
'e = (6 + 7) * 8'
'f = 0 and 1 or 2'
'a'
'b'
'c'
'e'
'f'
>>>
```

Comment: would applying the regex match to the `if` statement at the end of your generator comprehension do it?

Comment: No, one of the problems is that a statement like `a;b;c` only returns `('a', 'c')`, and `a#b` returns `('a', None)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be way off here-

```
>>> def tokenize(source):
...     search = re.compile(r'^(.+?)(?:;(.+?))*?(?:#.+)?$', re.MULTILINE)
...     return (token.strip() for line in source.split('\n') if search.match(line)
...                   for token in line.split('#', 1)[0].split(';') if token)
... 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> for token in tokenize('''\
... a = 1 + 2; b = a - 3 # create zero in b
... c = b * 4; d = 5 / c # trigger div error
... 
... e = (6 + 7) * 8
... # try a boolean operation
... f = 0 and 1 or 2
... a; b; c; e; f'''):
...     print(repr(token))
... 
'a = 1 + 2'
'b = a - 3'
'c = b * 4'
'd = 5 / c'
'e = (6 + 7) * 8'
'f = 0 and 1 or 2'
'a'
'b'
'c'
'e'
'f'
>>>
```

If applicable, I would keep the `re.compile` out of the `def` scope.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to get it all in a single regular expression that would do all of the tokenization work, but the code works well enough. Anyone else is still welcome to write `lambda source: re.finditer(PATTERN, source, FLAGS)` where they define PATTERN and FLAGS. It would be a great learning experience.

Comment: shouldn't you be `.strip()`ing the return value?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one based off of your tokenize2 function:

```
def tokenize2(source):
    search = re.compile(r'([^;#\n]+)[;\n]?(?:#.+)?', re.MULTILINE)
    for match in search.finditer(source):
        for item in match.groups():
            yield item

>>> for token in tokenize2('''\
... a = 1 + 2; b = a - 3 # create zero in b
... c = b * 4; d = 5 / c # trigger div error
... 
... e = (6 + 7) * 8
... # try a boolean operation
... f = 0 and 1 or 2
... a; b; c; e; f'''):
...     print(repr(token))
... 
'a = 1 + 2'
' b = a - 3 '
'c = b * 4'
' d = 5 / c '
'e = (6 + 7) * 8'
'f = 0 and 1 or 2'
'a'
' b'
' c'
' e'
' f'
>>>
```